# How to search in string array and check incorrect data by c#?

Tags: c#

how to correct, one string array with incorrect data ?
problem is don`t know what index into one index and insert to new string array

`incorrect` mean not good result for me.attention to `current result` and `final result` , final result is `goal` for me.

**must check index by index and `create final result` = `newline array`**

**current result is incorrect for me:**

```
var Cmpstr = new List<string> { "start#&", "End#&", "Success#&" };
string [] line = new string [13];
string [] newline = new string [13];
line[0]="start#&checkplease new comment for this pc#&checked and ok#&submit this";
line[1]="checked";
line[2]="incorrect data please recheck&#";

line[3]="End#&End check please new comment for this pc#&";
line[4]="checked ok&#";

line[5]="start#&checkplease new comment for this pc#&checked and ok#&submit this";
line[6]="checked this&#";
line[7]="incorrect data please recheck&#";
line[8]="checked ok&#";


line[9]="Success#&Success please new comment for this pc#&Success this&#";
line[10]="checked this&#";
line[11]="Success inter&#";
line[12]="Success ok&#";
```

**this array is incorrect and correct is (Final result):**

```
newline [0]="start#&checkplease new comment for this pc#&checked and ok#&submit this checked incorrect data please recheck&#";
newline [1]="End#&End check please new comment for this pc#&checked ok&#";
newline [2]="start#&checkplease new comment for this pc#&checked and ok#&submit this checked this&#incorrect data please recheck&#checked ok&#";
line[3]="Success#&Success please new comment for this pc#&Success this&#checked this&#Success inter&#Success ok&#";
```

Comment: Could you explain more properly what you have on input and what you expecting to get on result?

Comment: how is the first array incorrect?

Comment: What determines that an array is incorrect?

Comment: edit question,if not clear add comment please.

Comment: Can you provide some context as to what the code is trying to achieve? Also what does `create final result` = `newline array` mean? Are you trying to copy elements from `line` into `newline`?

Comment: final array is newline  -- yes first correct and into newline array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int newLineIndex = 0;
newline[0] = (string) line[0].Clone();

for (int i = 1; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    bool flag = false;
    if (line[i] == null) continue;
    foreach (string item in Cmpstr)
    {
        if (line[i].Contains(item))
        {
            newLineIndex++;
            newline[newLineIndex] += " " + line[i];
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag) continue;
    newline[newLineIndex] += " " + line[i];
}
```